# Flex 1 full width column then two columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have one full-width row/column then directly underneath I want 2 50% columns with inner padding.

For some reason, my code is putting everything on one row?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ro546yk/

```css
.a {display: flex}
.header {background: red;}
.col {flex: 50%; background: yellow; justify-content: space-between;}

// add inner padding on yellow columns
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="col">col 1</div>
  <div class="col">col 2</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: _“For some reason, my code is putting everything on one row?”_ - that is the default behavior of flexbox; if you want to allow items to break into multiple rows, then you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container element.

Comment: Tried that, i want the header 100% then two 50% columns below that. Using wrap it breaks everything onto a new row?

Comment: _“i want the header 100%”_ - then you need to specify that, otherwise it takes only the minimum width it needs - _because_ you are using flexbox.

Comment: thank you! Does this look right now? New to using flex, always been floats. http://jsfiddle.net/3ro546yk/1/

Answer (score -2):

I just update your code, with some UI and Structure changes. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background: red;
}

.col {
  background: yellow; 
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

// add inner padding on yellow columns
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="col-wrapper">
    <div class="col">col 1</div>
    <div class="col">col 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah right, so you need the column wrapper then? Is there a way to do it with the exact markup i used at all?